# WORDPRESS add_filter('cron_schedules', ...) not working in a PHP class

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I tried to declare a new time interval for a WP_CRON.
When I do it in a PHP file it works.
When I do it in a PHP Class it doesn't.

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong ?

I'm using the plugin [cron view](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cron-view/) to check if the declaration is working or not.

If I solve this problem I think it will also solve my problem to know why my cron job is not triggered in the class but works properly when not in a class.

=> File myplugin.php

```
function set_up_option_page() {
    add_options_page( [...]);
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'set_up_option_page' );

function do_some_rock() {

    $instance = My_Plugin_Class::instance();

    if ( isset($_POST['action']) && 'do-magic' == $_POST['action'] ) {
        $instance->do_stuff();
    }else{
        // Display the form.
    <?
    }
}
```

=> File My_Plugin_Class.php

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

class My_Plugin_Class {

    private static $_instance = null;

    public function __construct () {

[...] 

        add_filter( 'cron_schedules', array($this,'cron_time_intervals'));

    } 

    public function cron_time_intervals( $schedules ) {
        echo "——— cron time intervals —— ";
        $schedules['minutes_1'] = array(
            'interval' => 10*60,
            'display'   => 'Once 10 minutes'
        );

        return $schedules;
    }

    public static function instance () {
        if ( is_null( self::$_instance ) ) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    } // End instance ()
```

Best regards.

Comment: Do you instantiate your class every time when user visits your page?

Comment: Hello @lukas I'm pretty sure this the case. Well I first check is there is an existing instance of the class. 

 $instance = My_Class_Name::instance( __FILE__, '1.0.0' );
$instance->do_things();

Comment: Can you paste the whole class?

Comment: I see it now. You need to call add_filter( 'cron_shedules', .... ); every request - is that do_some_rock() function always called?

Comment: do_some_rock() is the call back of  add_options_page( );
I'm not sure it's call all the time, I guess not.
So where it make more sense to put my cron code ? and what is the best acording to the wordpress standard ? 
In the My_Plugin_Class, in a My_Plugin_Cron_class, or myplugin.php file (not a class) ? 
Regards,

Comment: I had to use Answer option as my comment was too long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the proper way to do this, is to have a specific class for my Cron.
This class is instanciated on each request this is why the code shouldn't be in a class with a static instance as I did before.
Also I think it's better to have the Cron outside the plugin class for logic and cleaner code purpose. Thanks to Lukas Pawlik for the help.

```
 if (!defined('ABSPATH')) exit;

    new My_Cron();

    class My_Cron {

        public function __construct() {
            add_filter('cron_schedules', array($this, 'cron_time_intervals'));
            add_action( 'wp',  array($this, 'cron_scheduler'));
            add_action( 'cast_my_spell', array( $this, 'auto_spell_cast' ) );
        }

        public function cron_time_intervals($schedules)
        {
            $schedules['minutes_10'] = array(
                'interval' => 10 * 60,
                'display' => 'Once 10 minutes'
            );
            return $schedules;
        }

        function cron_scheduler() {
            if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'cast_my_spell' ) ) {
                wp_schedule_event( time(), 'minutes_10', 'cast_my_spell');
            }
        }

        function auto_spell_cast(){
            My_Plugin_Class::instance()->launch_spell();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think the wp_schedule_event needs to be triggered only once and its during plugin activation see more details about it here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event

Answer (score 2):

I am almost sure that `do_some_rock()` is not called every time - only when someone goes to that page. You can move `add_filter( 'cron_schedules', array($this,'cron_time_intervals'));` from your class constructor to main plugin file myplugin.php and do more or less something like this

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'set_up_option_page' );
$instance = My_Plugin_Class::instance();
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', array($instance ,'cron_time_intervals'));
```

One extra question. Does `My_Plugin_Class` constructor contain any code you would like to prevent being executed during each request?

Answer (score 1):

I am not Sure But Try this.

```
   add_filter( 'cron_schedules', array($this,'cron_time_intervals'),1);
```

And Check cron_time_intervals() Function is Call or Not.

Comment: hello @dev, this also doesn't work. The add_filter seems not to triger because cron_time_intervals() function isn't call.